# Rails how to find id by another attr in a callback model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm looking to create  a callback where update a object if find the id attribute of another model.

in this case if find update Odata model if find the order_id.

someone know how to find the object based on another model id attribute?

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_update  :update_odata


  def update_odata
        order = Order.find_by_id(attributes['id'])
        od = Odata.find_by_id(attributes['order_id'])
        od.shipping_cost = order.shipping_cost
        od.shipping_method  = order.shipping_method
        od.status  = order.status
        od.feedback_id = order.feedback_id
        od.track_number  = order.track_number
        od.seller_name  = order.seller_name
        od.buyer_name  = order.buyer_name
       od.save

   end
end
```

Comment: As a note, if you need mentoring or coaching try services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [Hackhands](https://hackhands.com).

Answer (score 1):

In general you should [check the docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#read) and at least make an effort to learn the tools you're using before resorting to asking for someone to help explain it to you on StackOverflow.

To answer your question, `find(1)` is effectively a shortcut method for `find_by(id: 1)`. Thusly, if you want to *find* an *order* by *customer_id* you could do this: `Order.find_by(customer_id: 42)`.

Or, if you're trying to make this contingent on `order` (making some assumptions based on how Rails apps are built vs this unusual `attributes` stuff you have in your example):

```
order = Order.find(params[:id])
od = Odata.find_by(order_id: order.id)
```

In which case, you should probably just use relations:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :odata
end

class Odata < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
end

# controller:
order = Order.find params[:id]
od = order.odata
```

If you wanted to do exactly what you are above, which is probably a bad path to go down, you would probably want to do something like this:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :odata

  def attributes_for_odata
    %w{ shipping_cost shipping_method status feedback_id track_number seller_name buyer_name }
  end

  def update_order_data
    odata.update attributes.slice(*attributes_for_odata)
  end
end
```

Comment: sorry is not that so simple @coreyward

Comment: More specifically, `find(x)` is equivalent to `find_by!(id: x)` since `find` does throw exceptions on a failed lookup.

Comment: @bookaka It actually is if your question is asking what I think it's saying.

Comment: first the find is in the model not on the controller, second i'm looking to find by and not specific id

Comment: @bookaka What does that even mean?

Comment: @tadman that mean that or you guys did not get the question because this find_by method did not work on this scenario.

Comment: @bookaka You really need to explain better because nothing you've said makes any sense to me. Try to describe what you *want* to have happen, clear it up in your question by editing it.

Comment: @tadman Yeahhh, didn't want to get into bang methods and risk the additional confusion. Trading a little accuracy for understanding is worth it sometimes. ;)

Comment: and for your patience!

Comment: @bookaka See above answer.

Comment: @coreyward i testes your solution and:

undefined local variable or method `params' for #<Order:0x007fa22582c908>

Comment: @bookaka Params belongs in your controller. That's where this code would normally be. I'm not sure why you would actually have one model `Order` creating what is presumably an “Order Data” model as part of the `Order` model. As with any code, you'll need to adapt it to suit your application and needs.

Comment: @coreyward sorry for the delay, i know that. but in my order controller is not possible for find and associate and save or update the order_data on there.
and tell me please why is not a good procedure to do this on the model?